# Pandas dividing by multiple column entries

Tags: python, pandas, merge, dataframe, concatenation

New to Pandas. Wondering how to divide with a data frame that is grouped by multiple columns? I want to get the proportion of var3 (by some condition) 'var1' and 'var2'. One could think of this problem as finding the percent by time spent at work that are during normal business hours by day and occupation. Var 3 is time spent at work (conditioned by normal business hours for df2) grouped by day and occupation

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data) ###all data, here all time 
df2 = df[(df['hours'] > x)] ### subset, here all time during normal business hours

df = df.groupby(["var1", "var2"]).var3.sum()
df2 = df2.groupby(["var1", "var2"]).var3.sum()
normal_bus_hours_percent = (df2.div(df, level=['var1', 'var2']) * 100)
```

This fails TypeError: Join on level between two MultiIndex objects is ambiguous

Even if you could help me just merge these data frames. I get this error: 
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'

If I try to concatenate, i get this error:
TypeError: first argument must be a list-like of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "Series"

I came from R so I'm used to the easy cbind or merge.

Comment: which version of pandas are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Pandas aligns on index by default, does this not work?

```
 normal_bus_hours_percent = (df2.div(df) * 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about how you're doing that `groupby`. How does this look?

```
df1 = pandas.DataFrame([
    ['Atlanta', 'A', 1],
    ['Atlanta', 'A', 2],
    ['Atlanta', 'B', 3],
    ['Atlanta', 'B', 13],
    ['Boston', 'A', 4],
    ['Boston', 'A', 14],
    ['Boston', 'B', 5],
    ['Boston', 'B', 16],
    ['Portland', 'A', 7],
    ['Portland', 'A', 1],
    ['Portland', 'B', 9],
    ['Portland', 'B', 9],
    ['Seattle', 'B', 8],
    ['Seattle', 'B', 7],
    ['Seattle', 'C', 2],
    ['Seattle', 'C', 8],
], columns=['vars1', 'vars2', 'hours'])

df2 = df1[df1['hours'] > 6]

df1g = df1.groupby(by=['vars1', 'vars2']).sum()
df2g = df2.groupby(by=['vars1', 'vars2']).sum()

df2g.div(df1g).fillna(0)
```

Which yields:

```
                   hours
vars1    vars2          
Atlanta  A      0.000000
         B      0.812500
Boston   A      0.777778
         B      0.761905
Portland A      0.875000
         B      1.000000
Seattle  B      1.000000
         C      0.800000
```